# Request Spec Failing due to Redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, rspec, devise

I'm trying to do a simple test to make sure that when a user logs in it redirects them to the homepage with a 'successful sign in' message. However, when I run the test I keep getting the following response. I have attempted to change the after_sign_in_path_for(resource) to the root_url in application controller with no luck.

```
Failures:

  1) Users signs in a user
     Failure/Error: expect(response).to redirect_to(root_url)
       Expected response to be a <3XX: redirect>, but was a <200: OK>
     # ./spec/requests/user_spec.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'

Finished in 0.42947 seconds (files took 3.97 seconds to load)
6 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/user_spec.rb:4 # Users signs in a user
```

Here is the test
**user_spec.rb**

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe 'Users', type: :request do
  it 'signs in a user' do
    create(:user, email: 'test@test.com', password: 'password')
    get '/users/sign_in'
    post '/users/sign_in', params: { email: 'test@test.com', password: 'password' }
    expect(response).to redirect_to(root_url)
 expect(flash[:notice]).to eq('Signed in successfully.')
  end
end
```

**rails_helper.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require_relative '../config/environment'

abort('The Rails environment is running in production mode!') if Rails.env.production?
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'support/factory_bot'


  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!


  config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!

  config.include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods
  config.include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers, type: :request
end
```

**Application Controller**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include Pundit::Authorization
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: :index
  before_action :set_render_cart
  before_action :initialize_cart

  rescue_from Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, with: :user_not_authorized

  private

  def user_not_authorized
    flash[:alert] = 'You are not authorized to perform this action.'
    redirect_to(request.referrer || root_path)
  end

  def set_render_cart
    @render_cart = true
  end

  def initialize_cart
    @cart ||= Cart.find_by(id: session[:cart_id])
    if @cart.nil?
      @cart = Cart.create
      session[:cart_id] = @cart.id
    end
  end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does your `users/sign_in` controller method look like and did you disable the `:authenticate_user!` `before_action` in that controller?

Comment: We need to see the `users_controller` to be able to help.